# How to combine two dataframes df1 and df2 keeping common columns from df2

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have df1

```
+-----+------------------------+---------------------------+----------------------+---------+
|JobId|TotalRecordType1Count   |TotalRecordType2Count      |TotalRecordType3Count |JobStatus|
+-----+------------------------+---------------------------+----------------------+---------+
|  100|                       0|                          0|                     0|Success  |
+-----+------------------------+---------------------------+----------------------+---------+
```

df2 as

```
+---------------------------+----------------------+
|TotalRecordType1Count      |TotalRecordType2Count |
+---------------------------+----------------------+
|                        800|                   900|
+---------------------------+----------------------+
```

Both df1 and df2 will have only one row.

I want to combine df1 and df2 on common counts columns and keep the counts from df2

```
+-----+------------------------+---------------------------+----------------------+---------+
|JobId|TotalRecordType1Count   |TotalRecordType2Count      |TotalRecordType3Count |JobStatus|
+-----+------------------------+---------------------------+----------------------+---------+
|  100|                     800|                        900|                     0|Success  |
+-----+------------------------+---------------------------+----------------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a cross join and select the columns as needed:

```
val cols = df1.columns.map(x => if(df2.columns.contains(x)) df2(x) else df1(x))

result = df1.crossJoin(df2).select(cols:_*)

result.show
+-----+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+
|JobId|TotalRecordType1Count|TotalRecordType2Count|TotalRecordType3Count|JobStatus|
+-----+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+
|  100|                  800|                  900|                    0|  Success|
+-----+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+
```